# How is RedirectToRoute supposed to be used?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes, redirecttoroute

I have this in my Global.asax.cs:

```
routes.MapRoute("BetaAccess", "beta-access", new { controller = "Beta", action = "Index" });
```

And this in my controller (index action on HomeController) and it definitely is getting hit:

```
RedirectToRoute("BetaAccess");
```

But still no redirection happens... it just goes to the normal home page. Am I using it wrong?

Also, I can do Response.Redirect("~/beta-access") and it goes to the beta page...

Answer (score 46, accepted):

RedirectToRoute returns a RedirectToRouteResult. Try this instead.

```
return RedirectToRoute("BetaAccess");
```

Comment: I have to up-vote a comment that makes me laugh. (no worries, that's an easy mistake to make. :)

Answer (score 4):

This will redirect you.

```
Response.RedirectToRoute("BetaAccess");
Response.End();
```

Comment: I am having trouble with that too.... i am using it in webForms but i get this error : "A route named 'Students/Basic-Information' could not be found in the route collection.
Parameter name: name" ... i have defined the route like : " Routes.MapPageRoute("StudentsBasicData", "Students/Basic-Information", "~/Student/BasicInfo/BasicInfoCompletion.aspx");"