# Redirecting inside the controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I do some postdata handling on my webpage, but need some help with the redirecting.

How can i redirect as the code below does not work? I've breakpointed it and it enters `RedirectToRoute` function but goes to the return :(

```
            if (Session["auth"] != null)
                RedirectToRoute("/Home");

            return null;
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1290355/how-is-redirecttoroute-supposed-to-be-used

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return the RedirectToRouteResult like this:

```
if (Session["auth"] != null)
    return RedirectToRoute("/Home");

return null;
```