# How to Redirect to Error controller after NWebsec.Core.Exceptions.RedirectValidationException

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5, response.redirect

I have ASP.NET MVC 5 app but it does not matter if it is MVC 3, 4 or not. I have NWebSec 3.0 module installed with redirect validation enabled. I have Application_Error method ( even if I did not have one the problem is the same!):

```
    protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpContext httpContext = ((MvcApplication)sender).Context;
        Exception exception = Server.GetLastError();
        if(exception is NWebsec.Core.Exceptions.RedirectValidationException)
        {
            Trace.WriteLine("How to redirect from here to ErrorController/Index?");
        }
        else
        {
            Trace.WriteLine("How to redirect from here to ErrorController/Index?");
```

Herer are two test methods in HomeControllers :

```
    public ActionResult Redirect()
    {
        return new RedirectResult("http://www.deshow.net/d/file/travel/2010-04/bing-landscape-wallpaper-845-2.jpg");
    }

    public ActionResult ParseError()
    {
        int.Parse("test");
        return View();
    }
```

And I have standard shared error view and

```
 <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Error" />
```

enabled.

I expect that whatever the error I will be redirected to error view. But that is not true when I call the Redirect method. Somehow when the redirect error is thrown the standard 'custom errors' mechanism is bypassed and the standard error view is not displayed.

Another detail is that after ParseError() is hit then Application_Error is not hit and the standard 'custom errors' view is displayed but when Redirect() is hit there is no 'custom errors' view but yellow screen of death. This makes me think that maybe I am not understanding properly the 'pipeline' of the http modules.

NWebSec intersects with bad redirect and throws NWebsec.Core.Exceptions.RedirectValidationException. I suppose it is so because NwebSec is registered as a module

```
    <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      ...
    <add name="NWebsecHttpHeaderSecurityModule" type="NWebsec.Modules.HttpHeaderSecurityModule, NWebsec, Version=3.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3613da5f958908a1" />
    ...
    </modules>
    </system.webServer>
```

I read [the](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14621492/global-asax-redirecttoroute-not-working)-[e](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1171035/asp-net-mvc-custom-error-handling-application-error-global-asax)-[e](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25721554/redirect-to-shared-error-view-from-global-asax-on-mvc-unhandled-exception)-[e](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6211911/cant-get-defaultredirect-to-work)-[e](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1290355/how-is-redirecttoroute-supposed-to-be-used)-s answers already but I can not figure it out. Can you point me to an answer for such a problem or provide sample implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a RedirectValidation action on an ErrorsController, something like this should work:

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var routeData = new RouteData();
    routeData.Values["controller"] = "error";

    var exception = Server.GetLastError();

    if(exception is NWebsec.Core.Exceptions.RedirectValidationException)
    {
        routeData.Values["action"] = "redirectvalidation";
    }
    else
    {
        // handle everything else
    }

    Response.Clear();
    Server.ClearError();

    // Avoid IIS7 getting in the middle
    Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;

    IController errorsController = new Controllers.ErrorController();
    HttpContextBase wrapper = new HttpContextWrapper(Context);

    var rc = new RequestContext(wrapper, routeData);
    errorsController.Execute(rc);
}
```

It's basically the same thing one of your linked answers is doing, except that you handle that very specific type of exception. I do something similar for exceptions resulting from exceeding our upload size limit.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue. The [documentation](http://nwebsec.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Redirect%20validation&referringTitle=NWebsec) explains that 3.x version is slightly opportunistic on redirects. Therefore you have to whitelist approved url redirects (also allows custom ports).

In your config, update the allowSameHostRedirectsToHttps node.

```
<redirectValidation enabled="true">
  <allowSameHostRedirectsToHttps enabled="true" />
  <!--<allowSameHostRedirectsToHttps enabled="true" httpsPorts="4567, 7654"/>-->
  <add allowedDestination="http://www.nwebsec.com/"/>
  <add allowedDestination="https://www.google.com/accounts/"/>
</redirectValidation>
```

The error likely is thrown due to the error being thrown before headers have been sent. The documentation says you can call Response.Flush() if you'd like to get around it for your own custom errors.

Comment: Thank you for the tip! But my goal is to setup up the exception handling of really dangerous redirects. I do not want to white-list the danger which is not located on the same host - as you can see from the example I intentionally redirect to "http://www.deshow.net/d/file/travel/2010-04/bing-landscape-wallpaper-845-2.jpg" just for the tests sake. When a dangerous redirect is detected NWebSec throws this exception and I get it in global.asax. I need then to redirect to the RedirectError() action method of the ErrorController.