# What is optional parameter "Name" of MVC 5 Attribute Routing

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, attributerouting

In the attribute routing feature of MVC5 there is a option in attribute routing syntax for "Name" parameter e.g :
`[Route("Register/SetPassword", Name="SetPasswordGet")]`

My question is what is this **"Name="SetPasswordGet"** parameter ? and how to use it?

Comment: it is just for making unique routes what i guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the name as the parameter in the RedirectToRoute() method, see [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492497%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1290355/how-is-redirecttoroute-supposed-to-be-used)